# [SQL]ORACLE - Order By data and rows with the same id

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table with this data:

| id | parent_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10/01/2020 |
| 2 | 2 | 09/01/2020 |
| 3 | 2 | 11/01/2020 |
| 4 | 3 | 05/01/2020 |
| 5 | 2 | 01/01/2020 |

How i can group all rows with the same parent id and order by date?

I want this result:

```
3 | 2 | 11/01/2020
2 | 2 | 09/01/2020
5 | 2 | 01/01/2020
1 | 1 | 10/01/2020
4 | 3 | 05/01/2020
```

Not sure about advanced grouping or how to handle it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You formulation is not very *precise*. **Grouping** in `SQL` means `GROUP BY` which will lead to *one row* per `parent_id`. That contradicts with your *expectation*.

Comment: Ordering by date within each group - understood. But otherwise, your output doesn't seem ordered in any way. Don't you also want to order by parent first, and only then, for each parent, order by date? What you asked for can be done, but doesn't seem all that usual.

Comment: @mathguy, yeah i want to order each rows of the same group by 'date DESC' and after that only take the first row of each group for order all groups by 'date DESC' too, as u can see in the result, i have 1 group with 3 rows ordered by date desc and after that i have 2 more group ordered by date desc but referenced by the first row of group 1.

Comment: I guessed that was what you needed, after I read Gordon’s answer. He nailed it, that is the perfect answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions in the `order by`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by max(date) over (partition by parent_id),
         parent_id,
         date desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *  from T b
order by (select count(*) from T a where a.parent_id=b.parent_id) desc, date desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming where you say "group all rows" you mean "bring them together" (done by sorting, ie ORDER BY) perhaps you are looking for a hierarchical query. However what order you want cannot be determined as your result in not ordered by either id nor date.  
Also a caution about self referencing rows: they cause much more trouble than they are worth. Just let referencing column be null (in this case parent_id).  
But perhaps the following will get you somewhere: see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6e998c248f4c51e6bb9ff88655ceb74d).

```
with test ( id, parent_id, some_date) as 
     (select 1,1, to_date( '10/01/2020','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all 
      select 2,2, to_date( '09/01/2020','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all 
      select 3,2, to_date( '11/01/2020','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all 
      select 4,3, to_date( '05/01/2020','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual union all 
      select 5,2, to_date( '01/01/2020','mm/dd/yyyy') from dual
     ) 
   , normal  ( id, parent_id, some_date) as
     ( select id, nullif (parent_id, id) parent_id, some_date
         from test
    )         
select normal.*
  from normal
connect by  
        parent_id = prior id 
  start with 
        parent_id is null 
 order siblings by some_date;
```

Answer (score 0):

Create table statement:

```
create table testTable (ids int,parent_id int, dates date)
```

Inert values into table:

```
insert into testtable values(1, 1,  '10/01/2020')
insert into testtable values(2, 2,  '09/01/2020')
insert into testtable values(3, 2,  '11/01/2020')
insert into testtable values(4, 3,  '05/01/2020')
insert into testtable values(5, 2,  '01/01/2020')
```

Query to retrive information in your desired order:

```
select t.* from testtable t order by count(ids) over (partition by parent_id) desc, parent_id, dates desc
```